# Added addditional fee to sample product(price 0) not shows payment method magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: php

I have some sample products which are free but have some additional fee applied to total cart. If I order the sample product alone, it does not show any payment method so I can't able to choose payment method. How to show payment methods if the cart contains sample products alone with additional fee applied.

Comment: Are you adding the additional fee to Totat amount of cart?

Comment: Yes adding to the total amount

Comment: `additional fee` means shipping charges ?

Comment: yes, but not by using shipping method, have added customly

Comment: The free product is a virtual product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set the BaseSubtotal using

```
    $quote->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()+$additional_fee);
```

Setting the basesubtoal showed the payment methods for sample products.